# How to visualise neighbourhoods in function space topologies?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm wondering if there are established ways of visualising basic neighbourhoods in function spaces, something like this picture from Mukres:

[image]

Are there references in the literature about how this would look like for norm or strong topologies?